# Is cause of this equilibrium - tension or friction?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction

This is a very odd problem which I have.

As you can see in the diagram, the string is taut. So, if there was no friction you could clearly say that tension is balancing it or if there was no tension then friction is balancing it.[image]

But in this case where you have both tension and friction which would actually be the cause of the equilibrium ?

Or if we put it in another way, what should be the tension in the string ? 0 or greater?

Comment: As often with dry friction, there are an infinity of solutions. The "oddness" is that the problem is ill-posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, mathematically, any fraction of tension and friction is possible. Maybe this will help you to wrap your mind around this perhaps seemingly paradoxical situation: This math, and the mechanics it describes, is and can only ever be an approximation to the real world. Imagine you had actually balanced things so perfectly that the mass is supported by friction alone and the mass-less string only looks taunt but has zero tension. Then any ever so slight vibration would cause the mass to slide---if your idealized, mass-less and infinitely stiff string would not assume any tension necessary to prevent it from being stretched further even just the tiniest fraction of a micrometer.

In real life, unless you did not choose an incline where the mass was really about to slide even just from breathing on it, such a microscopic slide would occur and stretch the string to the point where it does stop further motion. The exact ratio of tensile and frictional force is then determined by possibly minuscule details of such a micro slide, the string's elasticity, the non-static coefficient of friction, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the free body diagram, you will get $$T = mg \sin \theta - \mu mg \cos \theta = mg (\sin \theta - \mu \cos \theta) $$ So, $T>0$ since $\theta$ is non-zero, $\mu$ is non-zero and $mg$ is also non-zero.

It is due to the equilibrium that we get to write the above equation. The 2 forces, namely tension and friction are in same direction as the gravitational component of the mass' weight is in the opposite direction.

If $T = 0$ then the mass would fall owing to the gravitational component of the mass' weight provided $$\mu \not = \tan \theta$$

If $\mu = \tan \theta$, then the mass would rest on the wedge even when the string has been detached, i.e. tension $T = 0$.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question....I was talking about when  μ=tanθ only(i mentioned in the diagram that friction is enough to have equilibrium). **My question is : does the tension or friction maintain equilibrium when  μ=tanθ ?**

Comment: @PhyPhy Yes of course. The equation itself implies that the frictional force is at work in maintaining equilibrium. At that point, T=0 i.e. the string slacks. However, if the string is made taut, then there is tension$(\not = 0)$ as friction which is a self adjusting force makes room for tension to have some value.

Comment: so you want to say, any one of the forces will act and we don't know which, right. @Aniket

Comment: @PhyPhy Friction will always be at work. That is mandatory. Tension may or may not act according as the string is taut or slack. Because you need to realise that whether the string is slack or taut does not matter when equilibrium is reached due to $\mu = \tan \theta$. If string is taut, then tension will have some magnitude as stated in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have one information (total tangential force) for two unknowns: there is no answer to this question as-is. Any combination of those forces will yield the expected behaviour.

If you want to know the actual tension/friction ratio, you need a more detailed description, maybe considering the rope as elastic.

Comment: Are you really sure that theres **NO** way at all?

Comment: Absolutely, UNLESS you add more information. Force balance perpendicular to the slope isn't giving anything concerning forces parallel to the slope. Parallel force balance gives you the sum of tension and static friction. That's it...

Comment: From an experimental point of view, imagine a car parked correctly (brakes on) on a slope. Put a rope from the car to your hand. However you pull on the rope, the car doesn't move. How, just looking the car not move, could anyone guess how hard you pull?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a gedanken experiment to show that there is no way to know the tension. Imagine that you have pulled the block slowly up to a certain position. The tension will be the sum of the gravitational force in the string direction plus the friction force, whether it be just a simple dynamic friction force or the static friction. You can slowly release tension on the string and the block will not move, but the tension on the string will decrease until the gravitational effect overcomes the friction. Therefore, it cannot be calculated.